# How to move breadcrumb to below main menu in custom module in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4

I created breadcrumb using layout.xml file but when i am go to that page breadcrumb is coming at the top of the page. what i need is below the main menu.

```
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs">
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Home</argument>
                <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Home</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Home</item>
                    <item name="link" xsi:type="string">{{baseUrl}}</item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Contact Us</argument>
                <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Contact Us</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Contact Us</item>
                </argument>
            </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

i created this for breadcrumb.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/qwpgrJG.png in Magento by default it's always under the menu where you need to move them

Comment: try this in your layut at last <move element="breadcrumbs" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/>

Answer (score 0):

This is magento's default code for menu on top of the page. but you can try with this code it's works for me.

```
<move element="breadcrumbs" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/>
```

or you can remove magento default breadcrumbs and create your new custom menu like this.

```
<referenceContainer name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
```